# SQL Update - Changing a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

```
Users(id,name)
```

I need a query to find name's start with 'asdf_' and update all rows with removing this prefix.

for example:

Before query, the table contains:

```
asdf_john
asdf_jane
```

After query I want:

```
john
jane
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sql-function you could use is Substring: SUBSTR (Example: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-substring.html)

For your table USERS:

```
UPDATE USERS SET NAME = SUBSTRING (NAME, 6) WHERE NAME LIKE 'asdf_%';
```

Comment: It's not entirely correct because the string to replace can have variable length (for example if passed as an argument to a function)

Comment: @Manji: ok but than you can use the function length to resolve the length of the string to replace

Comment: Hey, i have a problem , i used that syntax in a db like :            UPDATE urun SET NAME = SUBSTRING (NAME, 6) WHERE NAME LIKE 'chicco%' but it doesnt worked and the error is :  FUNCTION admin_vitrin_db.SUBSTRING does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Answer (score 1):

```
Update Users
set name = trim(leading 'asdf_' from name)
where name like 'asdf_%'
```

Comment: In Oracle PL/SQL, the underscore means a single jolly character, so you'll replace strings beginning with asdf1, asdf2, asdf3, ......, asdfZ and so on.

Comment: @UltraCommit: That's nice, but the question is tagged `mysql`.

Comment: But is is also tagged generically with SQL and QUERY, so if I state that IN ORACLE PL/SQL environment is has a different effect, I am not wrong.

Comment: @UltraCommit: I did not say that your statement was wrong. It isn't relevant though. :)

Comment: This will remove `asdf_` and `asdf_asdf_` and `asdf_asdf_asdf_` and `...`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `Users` SET `name` = replace(`name`, 'asdf_', '') WHERE `name` LIKE 'asdf\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Added the `WHERE` clause based on @UltraCommit's answer, so it replaces when it finds the string at the beginning.

OR as based on @McPepper's answer:

```
UPDATE `Users` SET `name` = SUBSTRING(`name`, 6) WHERE `name` LIKE 'asdf\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

If you want to replace only when the string is at the beginning. Replace the number `6` with the number of the characters the string you want to replace has `+ 1`.
In this case your string `asdf_` is `5` characters long, `+1` it becomes `6`. That's the character position where the DB will start keeping the string.

Comment: It's still wrong. What if the phrase is found at the beginning *and* in the middle?

Comment: @UltraCommit: Try not to act so surprised ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work by removing the starting "asdf_" only from all names that start with "asdf_"

```
UPDATE `Users` 
SET `name` = SUBSTRING(`name`, 6) 
WHERE `name` REGEXP '^asdf_';
```